# How to handle string "NAN' (Stock ticker) in datafame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have found a ticker "NAN" (NAN:NUVEEN NEW YORK QUALITY MUNICIPAL INCOME FUND) but when I am trying to insert it into my data frame it's converting into None. I even tried to insert as str(ticker) with the value of ticker being 'NAN'. I am lost - how do I do that. Every stock ticker is working except the ticker 'NAN'

Exact code:

## from previous code execution

```
ticker = 'NAN'
cusip = '67066X107'
cusipdf['ticker'] = np.where(( cusipdf['cusip'] == cusip ), str(ticker), cusipdf['ticker'] )
```

Comment: Can you paste your code where you read the info into cusipdf?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on pandas version `1.0.1` using an `np.where()`. What is your version? You can write: `pd.__version__` in your jupyter notebook. It actually might have to do with the version of `numpy` as well: my `np.__version__` is `1.18.1`

Comment: 0.25.3 -- Pandas
1.15.2 -- np

Comment: I am calling an API to get the data, I checked the values in varaibles, I am getting ticker as 'NAN' when I print. (Not NaN but actual NAN properly)

Comment: I am able to replace the value of `cusip` == `'67066X107'` to `NAN` using your query.

Comment: with open(cusip_file, 'r' ) as f:
        cusipdf= pd.read_csv( f, sep = ",", dtype = str, encoding = "latin1", \
                            error_bad_lines = True )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following and I am able to replace the value of `REPLACE` to `NAN`. See below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
c = ['ticker','cusip', 'value']
d = d = [['AMZN','51123X145',123.4567],
     ['REPLACE','62343X145',223.1237],
     ['AAPL','56789X225',312.5767],
     ['GOOG','42154X638',331.8793]]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)
print (df)

t = 'NAN'

df['ticker'] = np.where((df['cusip'] == '62343X145' ), str(t), df['ticker'] )
print (df)

    ticker      cusip     value
0     AMZN  51123X145  123.4567
1  REPLACE  62343X145  223.1237
2     AAPL  56789X225  312.5767
3     GOOG  42154X638  331.8793


  ticker      cusip     value
0   AMZN  51123X145  123.4567
1    NAN  62343X145  223.1237
2   AAPL  56789X225  312.5767
3   GOOG  42154X638  331.8793
```

Comment: Mine is an idiotic mistake - in the code, I was searching for string None and NaN and replacing with None. I really feel bad not reviewing the code and posting prematurely.. I sincerely apologize

Comment: All good. Glad you were able to figure out the code issue :) you are doing good.